# JS Удалить часть HTML кода

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как найти в коде страницы и удалить одинаковые фрагменты кода?
Если быть точным - то вот такие фрагменты:

```
<span style="COLOR:GRAY; TEXT-DECORATION:NONE;">опубликовано:</span>
```

Только не содержимое блоков, а полностью блоки удалить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script>
  var regex = /(<span style="COLOR:GRAY; TEXT-DECORATION:NONE;">).*(<\/span>)/ig;

  //удалит все серые "Опубликовано"
  document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(regex, "");
</script>
```

Рабочий пример тут https://jsfiddle.net/k0tcwdw8/

Comment: Нет. Удалит все серые

Comment: Самый гибкий ответ. Не сложно даже без знаний подкорректировать под необходимый результат.

Answer (score 1):

```
<span style="COLOR:GRAY; TEXT-DECORATION:NONE;">опубликовано:</span>


<script type="text/javascript">
var regex = /<span.+?="COLOR:GRAY.+<\/span>/ig;
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(regex,"");
</script>
```

Comment: Не работает(( По крайней мере так как надо не работает. Пропадают нужные блоки, а лишние все равно остаются.

Comment: можете покозать что значит нужные блоки?

Comment: @L.Vadim Ваша регулярка уничтожает первый попавшийся `span` серого цвета

Comment: <span>Мой текст</span>

Comment: @Павел мое решение удаляет все спаны серого цвета, ваш пример трогать не будет

Comment: направление верное, но удаляются не все лишние блоки.

Comment: какие не удаляется, дайте пример

Comment: пардон, стиль упустил в примере нужного блока. но это не проблема, цвет поменяю.

Comment: нужно добавить флаг `g` (global) чтобы искать по всему документу см. [флаги регулярных выражений в JavaScript](https://learn.javascript.ru/regexp-introduction#флаги)

Comment: @LukasPierce oops. добавил, опечатка

Comment: Вот такой остался:
<span style="COLOR:GRAY; TEXT-DECORATION:NONE;" >&nbsp;</span>
и пустой один:
<span style="COLOR:GRAY; TEXT-DECORATION:NONE;" ></span>

Comment: проверьте сейчас, я добавил в код глобал

Comment: Все работает! Спасибо. То что нужно)

Comment: хм... некоторые все равно остаются. Наверное из-за того что добавляются впередистоящим скриптом.

Comment: Что значит в переди стоящим, дайте пример кода

Answer (score 0):

```js
function deleteSpan() {
  var regex = /<span style="COLOR:GRAY; TEXT-DECORATION:NONE;">опубликовано:<\/span>/g;
  document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(regex, '');
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span style="COLOR:GRAY; TEXT-DECORATION:NONE;">опубликовано:</span>
  <br/>
  <span style="COLOR:GRAY; TEXT-DECORATION:NONE;">будет опубликовано:</span>
  <br/>
  <span style="COLOR:GRAY; TEXT-DECORATION:NONE;">опубликовано:</span>
</div>
<div>
  <span style="COLOR:GRAY; TEXT-DECORATION:NONE;">опубликовано:</span>
  <br/>
  <span style="COLOR:GRAY; TEXT-DECORATION:NONE;">будет опубликовано:</span>
  <br/>
  <span style="COLOR:GRAY; TEXT-DECORATION:NONE;">опубликовано:</span>
</div>
<button onclick="deleteSpan()">Delete</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
   function strip_tags( str ){  
        return str.replace(/<\/?[^>]+>/gi, '');
    }
```

А потом использовать вот так

```
strip_tags('<span style="COLOR:GRAY; TEXT-DECORATION:NONE;">опубликовано:</span>');
```

Comment: Использовать типа так?
<body onload="strip_tags('<span style="COLOR:GRAY; TEXT-DECORATION:NONE;">опубликовано:</span>')">

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?